# Restful web-service Issue,GET method is working,but POST method is responding there is no resource for path

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I have implemented a restful web-service in my Hybris 6.3(spring 4.3) using out-of-box extension.

The following is my controller code:-

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/{baseSiteId}/dealer")
public class DealerController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public DealerData getCatalogs() {
        DealerData dealerData = new DealerData();
       //my code
       ...................
       return dealerData;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public DealerData saveCatalogs(@RequestBody final DealerData dealerData) {
        //my code
        ...................
        return dealerData;
    }
}
```

DealerData class:-

```
private String uid;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
```

I am able to access the get method through the GET request using Postman/ Advanced REST client -

> http://localhost:9001/testcommercewebservices/v2/test-site/dealer

but couldn't access POST method -

> http://localhost:9001/testcommercewebservices/v2/test-site/dealer

with body raw as JSON

```
{
    "uid": "123",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "test"
}
```

Comment: You have different context paths for your GET and POST requests. Does the GET operation work for both?

Comment: yes.the GET will work for both.What shall I do to avoid that?how can I set context path for POST separately?

Comment: what is the status code that you get when you call from Postman?

Comment: status code is 404 Not Found.

Comment: Does the POST request have the proper content type header?

Comment: yes.it is application/json

Comment: In which extensions have you put this class? Have your resgistered a Jakson mapper in your classpath? Have you enable annotation-driven behaviour?

Comment: try to send the data using curl and check you are getting the response for post

Comment: @alain.janinm I have put the class in the same extension.Also added this cofiguration:<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation‌​.RequestMappingHandl‌​erAdapter"> <property name="messageConverters"><list><ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/></list></property> </bean> < id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackso‌​n2HttpMessageConvert‌​er"/> <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.Annota‌​tionMethodHandlerAda‌​pter"> <property name="messageConverters"><list><ref bean="jsonConverter"/></list> </property> </bean>

Comment: @JoeSebin If your class is in `tetscommercewebservices` and that this extension is generated from ant modulegen using ycommercewebservices, the jackson mapper is already registered. Make sure that your class is in a package that is listed in `context:component-scan` in springmvc-v2-servlet.xml

Comment: @alain.janinm yes,the class is in tetscommercewebservices adn extension generated using extgen template ycommercewebservices.my class is in v2.controller. I am able to find v2 in context:component-scan in springmvc-v2-servlet.xml.

Comment: @JoeSebin Ok that seems correct. Although I see a potential issue given your previous comment. You said you use ant extgen, but for commercewebservices, you should use ant modulegen, which will generate 3 extensions with the proper links between them. Maybe that's the issue. The other thing I'm not sure - have you ` implements java.io.Serializable` in your DealerData class.

Comment: @alain.janinm.yes,i used java.io.Serializable` in my DealerData class as well.ant modulegen is what pending.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to use `POST` method on live deployment instead of test one

`livecommercewebservices` vs `testcommercewebservices`

and

`test-site` vs `live-site`

Comment: POST method on live deployment also has the problem.